# Setting up an Anaconda powershell prompt profile in Windows Terminal

Tags: powershell, anaconda, windows-terminal

I tried to make a profile in Windows terminal which would emulate the behavior of the Anaconda Powershell prompt. When I right-click > properties on the Anaconda Powershell Prompt shortcut on my windows machine the "Target" field shows the following:

```
%windir%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command "& 'C:\Users\me\miniconda3\shell\condabin\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate 'C:\Users\me\miniconda3' "
```

On `cmd`, `%WINDIR%` evaluates to `C:\Windows`. So I created a new Windows Terminal and copied the contents of the "Target" field into the `commandline` parameter in the `settings.json` file:

```
{
    "commandline": "C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command '& C:\\Users\\amine\\Miniconda3\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1 ; conda activate C:\\Users\\amine\\Miniconda3'",
    "hidden": false,
    "guid":"{236722dd-af73-416e-b467-67bca56e114d}",
    "name": "Anaconda powershell prompt",
    "font": {"size": 10}
}
```

Unfortunately, when I check the `$env:path` associated with this profile, it still does not contain the Miniconda related paths. Furthermore, when I run `conda` I get that it is an unknown cmdlet. The `$env:path` is otherwise identical with a regular powershell prompt.

Why does my custom profile not a activate Anaconda in Windows Terminal? How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After having a look at [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/5852#issuecomment-689314717), I realized that the string I was passing to the `-command` parameter may have been incorrect. I changed `commandline` in the Windows Terminal profile to the following:

```
"C:\\Windows\\System32\\WindowsPowerShell\\v1.0\\powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -NoExit -Command & 'C:\\Users\\me\\Miniconda3\\shell\\condabin\\conda-hook.ps1' ; conda activate C:\\Users\\me\\Miniconda3"
```

Then it worked fine.